# I want to add a tag display to the product list displayed with the woocommerce shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a tag display under the title of the product list displayed with the woocommerce shortcode, but I do not know the web hook of the product list, and how to write the code as adding a function to function.php I do n’t know if that ’s OK. Would you please teach me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the hook you may looking for.

> `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title`

will add string after title on shop or archive page.  Also you can use `[producttags]` shortcode to display tag inside product description.

Add bellow code to your Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active theme or in any plugin file.

```
function firefog_tag_cloud() {
        $tags = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
        $args = array(
            'smallest' => 10,
            'largest' => 22,
            'unit' => 'px',
            'number' => 10,
            'format' => 'flat',
            'separator' => " ",
            'orderby' => 'count',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'show_count' => 1,
            'echo' => false
        );
        $tag_string = wp_generate_tag_cloud( $tags, $args );
        return $tag_string;
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'firefog_tag_cloud', 2 );
    add_shortcode('producttags', 'firefog_tag_cloud');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

It was helpful for the hook. Thank you.
I did not see it when I added the code you sent me.

`add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'after_shop_loop_item_title', 1 );
function after_shop_loop_item_title() {
 global $post;
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ); 
  $text = "<h3> (";
 foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $text .= $term->name;
 }
 $text .= ") </h3>";
 echo $text;
 
}`

So, once I implemented it with this code, I was able to display it.

Thank you.